# Null condition in derived column to switch to createdDate if UpdatedDate is NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, ssis

I have a table employee which contains:

- `createdDate`: creation date of an employee
- `updatedDate`: update date if there is a modification on an employee

This is an example:

```
EmployeeId createdDate updatedDate
54         2013-07-10  NULL
245        2016-06-29  2016-07-03
```

If the updatedDate is NULL, we will consider only the createdDate. I am using a derived column, how can I use the condition?

My query is like below:

```
SELECT IIF(ISNULL(updatedDate),createdDate , updatedDate)
FROM employee
```

Answer (score 3):

`ISNULL()` will be appropriate :

```
SELECT ISNULL(updatedDate, createdDate)
FROM employee e;
```

`ISNULL()` accepts two argument one is possible `null` values & other is replacement of `null` values.

Answer (score 2):

I would just use `coalesce()`. It does exactly what you ask for, *and* it is standard SQL (unlike `ISNULL()`, which is somehow vendor specific):

```
select coalesce(updatedDate, createdDate) from employee
```

Answer (score 1):

In your derived column, the condition must be like below :

```
ISNULL(UpdatedDate)  ? CreatedDate :  UpdatedDate
```